# google authentication using angular fire

Tags: angularfire

```
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import firebase from 'firebase/app';

    constructor(private afa: AngularFireAuth) {}

    login() {
      this.afa.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }
```

After clicking on the login button the popup load up but it doesn't show any data.
And when I use the redirect method it doesn't give back the data as shown in the [angularfire documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Authentication/Sign-in Methods in the firebase console and enable Google as a sign in method for your app. Also this function doesnt return anything.

```
async login() {
    const credential = await this.afa.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
    return credential.user
}
```

In you code the promise is not even resolved when the login function finishes.

Make it an async function, await the promise and then return the result.

Comment: Thanks. But when I click the login button the popup window is opened but no data is displayed there.